# Alfresco ServiceRegistry could not be injected in Junit

Tags: java, spring, alfresco, autowired

I'm trying to create a test environment for my **Alfresco SDK** app. I need to test a service created by me that has **ServiceRegistry** as a property, injected by Spring through the constructor. If the app is running the service works well.

For bean declarations I'm using annotations:

```
@Service(value = "customFormService")
public class CustomFormService implements FormService<String> {
  private final ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry;

  @Autowired
  public CustomFormService(ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry) {
    this.serviceRegistry = serviceRegistry;
  }
```

In the service application context:

> /amp/config/module/sampleapp/context/service-context.xml

I declared   `<context:component-scan base-package="com.base"/>` to enable annotated components scanning

The problem is when I try to create an unit test like this:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(
  locations = {"classpath*:config/alfresco/module/sampleapp/context/service-context.xml"}
)
public class DocumentManagementTest {
  @Autowired
  @Qualifier(value = "customFormService")
  FormService<String> customFormService;

  @Test
  public void testWiring() {
    Assert.assertNotNull(customFormService);
  }
}
```

I get an exception:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.base.form.service.FormService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true), @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=customFormService}
```

It's very confusing that the injection works fine when the app is running and it fails in the Junit test case.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this one? I am looking for one as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to inject **ServiceRegistry** in your class then you need to add property

```
 <bean id="reject-content" class="com.repo.RejectContent"
        parent="action-executer">
        <property name="serviceRegistry">
            <ref bean="ServiceRegistry" />
        </property>


    </bean>
```

to your bean like above.
`com.repo.RejectContent` 
and in RejectContent class you need to create setter for service registry like this :

```
private ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry;

public void setServiceRegistry(ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry) {
    this.serviceRegistry = serviceRegistry;
}
```

After that you can use **serviceRegistry** .

Comment: I don't think this can solve my problem. The injection works fine if I run the app. The problem is more Junit related.

Comment: Sorry , I don't have more idea about JUnit

Answer (score 0):

```
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;
...

ApplicationContext applicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(new String[] { "classpath:alfresco/application-context.xml" });
ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = (ServiceRegistry) applicationContext.getBean(ServiceRegistry.SERVICE_REGISTRY);
...
```